# How Can I import .xlsx(Excel) file to Oracle ?

Tags: excel, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

My problem is I want to import Excel file Oracle 12c Database but not in SQL developer tools. with PL/SQL code.

I tried this,

```
create table OrnekTablo3(

ad char(100),
soyad char(100)) ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL(TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
DEFAULT DIRECTORY ext_tab_dir
ACCESS PARAMETERS(RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
FIELDS (
ad char(100),
soyad char(100))
)
 LOCATION ('C:\Users\hrh_a_000\Desktop')
 );
```

but it's not work the massage like that

```
ORA-29913: ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN başvurusunu yürütme hatası
ORA-29400: veri kartuşu hatası
KUP-04001: error opening file /usr/apps/datafiles\ORNEKTABLO3_9108_10720.log
29913. 00000 -  "error in executing %s callout"
*Cause:    The execution of the specified callout caused an error.
*Action:   Examine the error messages take appropriate action.
```

How can I browse in web page a Excel file and import Oracle Database ?

Thnx

Comment: Whats the directory `ext_tab_dir` pointing to? Seems you are working on Windows but provided the directory path for linux. This might be helpful http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/saternos-tables-090560.html

Comment: Thanks a lot ı worked. I missed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error information the path(`/usr/apps/datafiles`) directory object pointing to is invalid for Windows.

Since you are using Windows modify the directory object `ext_tab_dir` validate the path.

Here is a OTN article which explains how to import data from MS Excel file using External Table.

[Generate External Table from an Excel Spreadsheet](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/saternos-tables-090560.html)